# Adding data to list - JDBC

Tags: java, list, loops, jdbc

I want to put all the data that I have in my database in an ArrayList.

```
        ResultSet rs = callableStatement.executeQuery();
        ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        List<ArrayList> table = null;

        while (rs.next()) {

                for (int i = 1; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount() + 1; i++) {
                System.out.print(" " + rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i) + "=" + rs.getObject(i));

                    String data = rs.getString(i);
                    list.add(data);

                }
                table.add(list);
                System.err.println(table);
            }
```

I am printing all the data in my database correctly. My problem is that I'm getting

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: You are only printing `list.get(9)` You need to loop through each index in the list. Also, you should be using `System.out.println()` instead of `System.err.println()`. Although, your IDE will print them both to the console, `err` should be designated for errors.

Comment: @nLee with the `list.get(9)` I'm printing the 9th column (but just the first element, I want all the elements). Doing the `sys.err`  just so it's in red

Comment: `list.get(9)` will print the `9`th element of the `List`

Comment: Yes, that's right. The list is working as a line here. But I'm not getting the other lines from the `rs.next()`

Comment: ArrayList is not a table.  Are you trying to put only one column?

Comment: Major edit, sorry guys, the problem wasn't clear

Comment: @Jose Martinez I have a database with 10 columns by 10 lines in sql. I want to add the data to a List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am printing all the data in my database correctly. My problem is that I'm getting
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException

```
List<ArrayList> table = null;
```

followed by a

```
table.add(list);
```

without init `table` like

```
table = new ArrayList<ArrayList>(); //Consider some rework here ;)
```

will ofc cause a npe

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you should do like the following, in your code, you just print the ninth element repeatedly int the `list`

```
while (rs.next()) {
    for (int i = 1; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount() + 1; i++) {
        System.out.print(" " + rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i) + "=" + rs.getObject(i));
        String data = rs.getString(i);
        list.add(data);

    }
}

for (Object obj : list) {
    System.out.println(obj.toString())
}
```

if you want to print the 9th column, you should do like the following

```
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString(9))
}
```

or

```
    while (rs.next()) {
    for (int i = 1; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount() + 1; i++) {
        System.out.print(" " + rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i) + "=" + (i));
        if (i == 9) {
            String data = rs.getString(i);
            list.add(data);rs.getObject
        }
    }
}

for (Object obj : list) {
    System.out.println(obj.toString())
}
```

Comment: I want to store the data line by line, each line has many columns